# How to get a list of collections on a matplotlib figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, figure

I am trying to get a list of collections (scatter plots) on a particular matplotlib figure.

For normal line plots this can be accomplished by

```
lines = [ line for axis in figure.axes for line in axis.get_lines()]
```

where `axis.get_lines()` will give me a list of line objects associated with that axis. How do I do a similar operation for `PathCollections` or collections in general? The object figure.axes does not seem to have a `.get_collections()` option?

Note: I have done this using `axes.get_legend_handles_labels()` and just used the handles but this only works if each scatter has a label as well, as far as I can tell.

Comment: did you check other functions in axis - `print( dir(axis) )` ? Maybe it has `ax.get_paths()` or `ax.collections`

Comment: @furas I tried your suggestion and found an 'ax.collections'. Then changed `lines = [ line for axis in figure.axes for line in axis.get_lines()]` to `lines = [ line for axis in figure.axes for line in axis.get_lines()+axis.collections]`. I was then able to use `line.set_color` but the legend for the collections didn't update. Any ideas?

Comment: It hard to say anything without "minimal working example". Probably you have to get current legend and replace all data manually.

Comment: `axis.collections` is a list of collections, including the ones with no labels.

Answer (score 0):

i know this is a 7 years old question at this point, but i ran into the same issue. i tried @Matt's method (`axis.get_lines()+axis.collections`), but legend text color  mismatch with that of the plot when when scatter plot gets added in between lines plot. i was able to solve this by getting all handles & text of a a legend object. next get the handles color and then set color to text of the legend.

```
handlers, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
for handle, label, text in zip(handlers, labels, self.legends.get_texts()):
          try:
              text.set_color(handle.get_color())
          except:
              text.set_color(handle.get_facecolors())
```